# Find the right child-class during iteration of father-class Generics/Java/OOP

Tags: java, oop, iteration

I think explaining my question via code is easier.

Given a sales company which has 2 sales employee for example:

```
public class Employee()
{
private int salary;
}
public class SalesEmployee1 extends Employee()
{
private int commisionRate;

}

public class SalesEmployee2 extends Employee()
{
private int commisionRate;
}
```

Suppose I have a vector: `Vector<Employee> v = new Vector<>();`
I need to iterate over that vector and find the SalesEmployee1 with the lowest commission(each salesEmployee computes it differently so its a different commission) .
How can I ask whether I am a SalesEmployee1 without using instanceof?
I thought about adding a function in the father class which every child overrides

```
public boolean myClass(String name)
{
    return name.equals(ClassName for example SalesEmployee1);
}
```

and than do something like that:

```
for(Employee e : v)
{
    if(e.myClass("SalesEmployee1")
         doSmth()...
}
```

Is this method right? can anyone suggest another solution because I feel like im doing somthing wrong because this feels like a instance of variation.
Thanks!

Comment: You can get the class name of an object of unknown type by calling (depending on you use case) either `getName` or `getSimpleName` on the `Class` of the unknown object - e.g. `myObject.getClass().getName()`

Comment: @TheHeadRush it feels like using instanceof by a different method, is this the right solution for my problem? Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: You've got a bug in that you store the salary in the Employee class as well as the SalesEmployee1 class, so you shadow that variable. Secondly, you should probably use instanceof in this case.

Comment: @AlBlue you are correct , I changed the private field to better the example. and added an explanation(each salesEmployee computes it differently so its a different commission). I cant use instanceof this is my question.

Comment: You could simply cast the `Employee` to a `SalesEmployee1` and catch and ignore the `ClassCastException`. But why the aversion to using `instanceof` ?

Comment: @Abra because im a student and using instanceof is the forbbiden fruit.

Comment: If you structure your classes as given, probably you can achieve what you want:`public abstract class Employee {private double salary;public abstract double computeCommission();}
class SalesEmployee extends Employee {private double sales; public double computeCommission() {return sales * 0.3;}}
class StoreEmployee extends Employee {private double thingsSorted;public double computeCommission() 
{return thingsSorted * 0.15; }}`

Comment: @Mohammad this wont work because what ill get back is just a commission, but I wont know who gave me that commission, a StoreEmployee or a SalesEmployee. Since I need the highest commission of a StoreEmployee and not just any Employee.

Comment: @user615297 `toString()` would print the Employee type. `public String toString() { return StoreEmployee{" + "commission=" + computeCommission() + '}'; }` . What exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you share some more details. Or share the problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

The whole purpose of object-orientated programming, is that each (sub-)class knows its own behaviour. There should be no need to detect the specific class of an object at run-time. It an indication that something is wrong in your design, if you feel the need to detect the class of an object.

The different types of employees should know themselves how to calculate the commission:

```
public class Employee()
{
    abstract int calculateCommission();
}
public class SalesEmployee1 extends Employee()
{
    int calculateCommission() { ... }

}

public class SalesEmployee2 extends Employee()
{
    int calculateCommission() { ...}
}
```

Then you can through all Employees to find the lowest commission:

```
for(Employee e : v) {
    int commission = e.calculateCommission();
    // do something with the commission;
}
```

Comment: Im 100% sure you are right, its an exercise given in a homework. Im positive the question itself is incorrect and now I understand it, but still had to ask if there is a way. thanks for all the help.